# GraphDiff and EF6.1 – Recursive Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: entity-framework, recursion, graphdiff

I am having an issue with GraphDiff attaching an object which has a recursive many-to-many relationship. I am using GraphDiff 2.0.1 and Entity Framework 6.1.1.

The progam manages Recipes which can have 0-n RecipeLines which contains a link to another Recipe which is the ComponentRecipe and this has RecipeLines and so on.

I pass a Recipe Object into the repository which has 1 recipe line with the Recipe object on the line pointing back to the parent and the ComponentRecipe object pointing to a different recipe.

When GraphDiff attaches the item then the attachedItem it returns has 2 recipe lines and both of these are the same and have the ComponentRecipe point to the same object as the Recipe which creates a loop on itself.

I am not sure if this is an issue with GraphDiff or more likely I have something wrong in my EF mappings or my GraphDiff mappings. Any help appreciated, let me know if you need more information and I can provide a simple program that demonstrates this issue.

**Domain Models**

```
public class Recipe : EntityBase
{
        public override object Key
        {
            get { return Id; }
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<RecipeLine> RecipeLines { get; set; }

 }

public class RecipeLine : EntityBase
{
        public override object Key
        {
            get { return Id; }
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int RecipeId { get; set; }

        public int ComponentRecipeId { get; set; }

        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

        public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }

        public virtual Recipe ComponentRecipe { get; set; }
}
```

**Data Context**

```
class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext()
            : base("Connection")
        {
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().ToTable("Recipes");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

            modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeLine>().ToTable("RecipeLines");
            modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeLine>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeLine>().Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeLine>().Property(x => x.RecipeId).HasColumnName("RecipeId");
            modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeLine>().Property(x => x.ComponentRecipeId).HasColumnName("ComponentRecipeId");
            modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeLine>().Property(x => x.Quantity).HasColumnName("Quantity").HasPrecision(18, 5);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>().HasMany(x => x.RecipeLines).WithRequired(x => x.Recipe).HasForeignKey(x => x.RecipeId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeLine>().HasRequired(x => x.ComponentRecipe).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ComponentRecipeId);

        }
    }
```

**Repository**

```
public override void UpdateEntity(IEntity entity)
{
            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
                var item = (Recipe)entity;
                var attachedItem = context.UpdateGraph(item,
                    a => a.OwnedCollection(b => b.RecipeLines, c => c.AssociatedEntity(d => d.ComponentRecipe)));
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
}
```

**Data Context Log on Attach**

```
Opened connection at 14/09/2014 16:57:06 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
    [Project1].[RecipeId] AS [RecipeId], 
    [Project1].[ComponentRecipeId] AS [ComponentRecipeId], 
    [Project1].[Quantity] AS [Quantity], 
    [Project1].[Id2] AS [Id2], 
    [Project1].[Name1] AS [Name1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Limit1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Join1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
        [Join1].[RecipeId] AS [RecipeId], 
        [Join1].[ComponentRecipeId] AS [ComponentRecipeId], 
        [Join1].[Quantity] AS [Quantity], 
        [Join1].[Id2] AS [Id2], 
        [Join1].[Name] AS [Name1], 
        CASE WHEN ([Join1].[Id1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (2) [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
            FROM [dbo].[Recipes] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE 11 = [Extent1].[Id] ) AS [Limit1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent2].[RecipeId] AS [RecipeId], [Extent2].[ComponentRecipeId] AS [ComponentRecipeId], [Extent2].[Quantity] AS [Quantity], [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id2], [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name]
            FROM  [dbo].[RecipeLines] AS [Extent2]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Recipes] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ComponentRecipeId] = [Extent3].[Id] ) AS [Join1] ON [Limit1].[Id] = [Join1].[RecipeId]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC


-- Executing at 14/09/2014 16:57:06 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 14/09/2014 16:57:06 +01:00

Opened connection at 14/09/2014 16:57:07 +01:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM [dbo].[Recipes] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = 10


-- Executing at 14/09/2014 16:57:07 +01:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 14/09/2014 16:57:07 +01:00
```

**Data Context Log on SaveChanges**

```
Opened connection at 14/09/2014 16:58:45 +01:00

INSERT [dbo].[RecipeLines]([RecipeId], [ComponentRecipeId], [Quantity])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[RecipeLines]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()


-- @0: '11' (Type = Int32)

-- @1: '11' (Type = Int32)

-- @2: '1' (Type = Decimal, Precision = 18, Scale = 5)

-- Executing at 14/09/2014 16:58:46 +01:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 14/09/2014 16:58:46 +01:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in GraphDiff. The code to attach parent navigation properties wasn't ready to handle multiple parents of the same type. I've just fixed that on the `develop` branch with [pull request #102](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff/pull/102).